# How to sort a numpy array with key as isnan?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like

```
np.array([[1.0, np.nan, 5.0, 1, True, True, np.nan, True],
       [np.nan, 4.0, 7.0, 2, True, np.nan, False, True],
       [2.0, 5.0, np.nan, 3, False, False, True, np.nan]], dtype=object)
```

Now I want to sort the values with key as isnan? How can I do that? So that I would end up in the array

```
np.array([[1.0, 5.0, 1, True, True, True, np.nan, np.nan],
   [4.0, 7.0, 2, True, False, True, np.nan, np.nan],
   [2.0, 5.0, 3, False, False, True, np.nan, np.nan]], dtype=object)
```

`np.sort()` didn't work. The same can be achieved in pandas by applying sorted over columns with `sorted` function with key as pd.isnull(), but looking for a numpy answer for speed.

In pandas

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [1, 2, 3], 'Var': [True, True, False], 'ID_1':[1, np.NaN, 2],
                'Var_1': [True, np.NaN, False], 'ID_2': [np.NaN, 4, 5], 'Var_2': [np.NaN, False, True],
                'ID_3': [5, 7, np.NaN], 'Var_3': [True, True, np.NaN]})

data.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1).values
```

Output :

```
array([[1.0, 5.0, 1, True, True, True, nan, nan],
   [4.0, 7.0, 2, True, False, True, nan, nan],
   [2.0, 5.0, 3, False, False, True, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: can `nan` be ordered?

Comment: Just curious how did you end up with an object dtype array, as the no. of elems look to be same per row/list.

Comment: Where do you want the nan's to end up in the ordering? In their own row/column, or at the end of one?

Comment: Yes at the end per row.

Comment: Show how you tried to sort it.

Comment: @Bharathshetty. Not a link. Post your actual code that you ran.

Comment: That still does not show what you did in numpy.

Comment: Im dumb in numpy all I did is `np.sort(data.values)` which dint work. Since the values is a numpy array just to know whether this can be with any numpy function or any numpy based approach.

Comment: Also, why did you not try to use the `axis` parameter to `np.sort`?

Comment: When you say it "didn't work", what happened?

Comment: You might want to edit the sample input array listed in the question, as it differs from `data.values`.

Comment: They are same na I added np.nan for the sake of easy copy paste of data.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Took the liberty to edit the sample input as `data.values`. Hope that's okay. Feel free to edit if that's not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized approach borrowing the concept of `masking` from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299218/) -

```
def mask_app(a):
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    mask = np.isnan(a.astype(float))
    mask_sorted = np.sort(mask,1)
    out[mask_sorted] = a[mask]
    out[~mask_sorted] = a[~mask]
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
# Input dataframe
In [114]: data
Out[114]: 
   ID_1  ID_2  ID_3  Key    Var  Var_1  Var_2 Var_3
0   1.0   NaN   5.0    1   True   True    NaN  True
1   NaN   4.0   7.0    2   True    NaN  False  True
2   2.0   5.0   NaN    3  False  False   True   NaN

# Use pandas approach for verification    
In [115]: data.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull),1).values
Out[115]: 
array([[1.0, 5.0, 1, True, True, True, nan, nan],
       [4.0, 7.0, 2, True, False, True, nan, nan],
       [2.0, 5.0, 3, False, False, True, nan, nan]], dtype=object)

# Use proposed approach and verify
In [116]: mask_app(data.values)
Out[116]: 
array([[1.0, 5.0, 1, True, True, True, nan, nan],
       [4.0, 7.0, 2, True, False, True, nan, nan],
       [2.0, 5.0, 3, False, False, True, nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

**Approach #2**

With few more modifications, a simplified version with the idea from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559180/) -

```
def mask_app2(a):
    out = np.full(a.shape,np.nan,dtype=a.dtype)
    mask = ~np.isnan(a.astype(float))
    out[np.sort(mask,1)[:,::-1]] = a[mask]
    return out
```

Comment: I was waiting for you . :)

Comment: I would love to give bounty for this solution. This is beautiful.

Comment: Sir a small question how long have you been working with vecotrizing a solution.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Vectorizing this particular solution, you mean?

Comment: Sir no no no your experience with numpy and vectorization . You can vectorize any kind of for loops :) so

Comment: @Bharathshetty It's been a while. I started off with MATLAB. Loved vectorizing stuffs on it. Heard about NumPy and jumped on it and it has its own unique/interesting capabilities and have been hooked ever since to it. I get to answer MATLAB questions sometimes too these days. But yeah I generally try to think that I need to avoid loops and that helps I think :)

Comment: I should try to vectorize as many for loops as I can. I too don't like loops. Though vectorizing is very very tricky and my dumb brain is not ready for it yet. :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an object array anyway, do the sorting in Python, then make your array. You can write a key that does something like this:

```
from math import isnan

def key(x):
    if isnan(x):
        t = 3
        x = 0
    elif isinstance(x, bool):
        t = 2
    else:
        t = 1
    return t, x
```

This key returns a two-element tuple, where the first element gives the preliminary ordering by type. It considers all NaNs to be equal and greater than any other type.

Even if you start with data in a `DataFrame`, you can do something like:

```
values = [list(sorted(row, key=key)) for row in data.values]
values = np.array(values, dtype=np.object)
```

You can replace the list comprehension with [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) if that suits your needs better:

```
values = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: np.array(list(sorted(row, key=key))),
                             axis=1, arr=data.values)
```

Comment: Can this be done with something like `apply_along_axis`?

Comment: @Bharathshetty. You can replace the list comprehension with `apply_along_axis`. I will show an example, but I doubt it will speed things up any. You will still be using the Python `sorted` function and a Python key.

Comment: The problem is that I am not aware of any way to specify a custom key to the numpy machinery. There may be one, but I have looked at this in *a lot* of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an `object` array and `nan` You would need to find a numeric type everything would fit into. When used as an object instead of as a float, `nan` returns false for `<`, `>`, and `==`.

Additionally, `True` and `False` are equivalent to 0 and 1, so I don't think there is any way to get your expected result.

You would have to see if converting the `dtype` to `float` would give you proper results for your use case.