# Discarding randmly scattered empty spaces in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How to ignore empty cells inside a data frame that are randomly spread across the data frame? here is an example of what i have

```
 ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColF    ColG    ColH
  A               b                                D
          W                      R                 D
  J                        H              T 
  Q               A                                O
```

There is always 3 entries in each row, but the empty cells are random. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-empty-cells) but it is not helpful because of the randomness in my data

The output I am expecting is:

```
 ColA_New    ColB_New    ColC_New     
  A        b       D      
  W        R       D               
  J        H       T        
  Q        A       O
```

Comment: There are lot of repition for this. But everyone with different heading

Comment: Are those blank spaces NaN's

Comment: I replaced them with NaNs to see if I solve it using the answer I referred to, but it did not work because of the randomness. DF.dropna is not helpful either here because I will wither drop the whole column or to keep it as a whole, I can not just extract the non empty cells from each column

Comment: Is my solution you looking for ?

Comment: @owise Is this what your CSV looks like? This step can possibly be solved when you load your data actually. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46847649/4909087).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also with

```
ndf = df.replace('',np.nan).apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull,axis=1).add_suffix('_NEW')
ndf = ndf.loc[:,~ndf.isnull().all()]
```

```
 ColA_NEW ColB_NEW ColC_NEW
0        A        b        D
1        W        R        D
2        J        H        T
3        Q        A        O
```

Answer (score 5):

similar to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution:

```
In [185]: pd.DataFrame(df.stack().values.reshape(-1,3), 
                       columns='ColA_New ColB_New ColC_New'.split(), 
                       index=df.index)
Out[185]:
  ColA_New ColB_New ColC_New
0        A        b        D
1        W        R        D
2        J        H        T
3        Q        A        O
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your blank spaces are `NaN`s, use `df.notnull` in conjunction with numpy's indexing and `reshape`. Note that the fancy column naming logic works for any number of columns.

```
print(df)
  ColA ColB ColC ColD ColF ColG ColH
0    A  NaN    b  NaN  NaN  NaN    D
1  NaN    W  NaN  NaN    R  NaN    D
2    J  NaN  NaN    H  NaN    T  NaN
3    Q  NaN    A  NaN  NaN  NaN    O

m = df.notnull()
x = m.sum(1).max()

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[m].reshape(-1, x))\
           .rename(columns=lambda x: 'Col_' + chr(ord('A') + x))

print(df)
  Col_A Col_B Col_C
0     A     b     D
1     W     R     D
2     J     H     T
3     Q     A     O
```

If, instead, your dataframe contains blanks, then use `df.ne`, and the rest is the same.

```
m = df.ne('')
```

---

If this is how your CSV file looks, then you don't need any of this. Instead, the problem can be nipped in the bud while loading your CSV, using `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=1, delim_whitespace=True)
```

If needed, you can rename your columns using `rename` as described above.

Comment: better to consider then as `''` rather than NaN

Comment: @Bharathshetty Edited.

Comment: Curious just add another letter into the randomnly scattered data in case you want 4 columns then ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty If every row has N elements, then it'd work. But if even one row had a different number of elements, it fails.

Comment: You know I have a 100 times faster solution for sorted interested using numpy ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326140/how-to-sort-a-numpy-array-with-key-as-isnan check this out. Divakar made an alternative solution

Comment: @Bharathshetty But this isn't sorting, this is just an index + reshape, so it's even faster.

Comment: I dont know I get to that sorting solution whenever I see this kind of problems. I love the read_csv solution though

Comment: @Bharathshetty Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Solution with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1)
df1.columns = df.columns[:len(df1.columns)]
print (df1)
  ColA ColB ColC
0    A    b    D
1    W    R    D
2    J    H    T
3    Q    A    O
```

Comment: Also, `df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist(), axis=1).tolist())`